# QVBoxLayout how to add spacer row

Tags: c++, qt

Is it possible to add a spacing row to a QVBoxLayout?  I tried using a QPushButton and then hiding, but this doesn't work.

I want the layout to contain 5 buttons with a spacing row between buttons 4 and 5.

Comment: Take a look at [QSpacerItem](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qspaceritem.html)

Comment: Adding an empty `QLabel` could work as well.

Comment: @RomhaKorev, excellent thank you, that works!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to handle the `QSpacerItem` yourself (the [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qspaceritem.html) lists the methods you should use instrad of creating the `QSpacerItem`).

If you want to add a space with a specific size, you can use `QVBoxLayout::addSpacing()`:

```
    QWidget* w = new QWidget();
    QVBoxLayout* layout = new QVBoxLayout(w);
    layout->addWidget(new QPushButton("first"));
    layout->addWidget(new QPushButton("second"));
    layout->addWidget(new QPushButton("third"));
    layout->addWidget(new QPushButton("fourth"));
    layout->addSpacing(50);
    layout->addWidget(new QPushButton("fifth"));
    w->show();
```

It will be a minimum space of 50 pixel between *fourth* and *fifth*:

[image] [image]

If you want to put the button *fifth* at the bottom and keep the others at the top, use `QVBoxLayout::addStretch()`:

```
    QWidget* w = new QWidget();
    QVBoxLayout* layout = new QVBoxLayout(w);
    layout->addWidget(new QPushButton("first"));
    layout->addWidget(new QPushButton("second"));
    layout->addWidget(new QPushButton("third"));
    layout->addWidget(new QPushButton("fourth"));
    layout->addStretch(1);
    layout->addWidget(new QPushButton("fifth"));
    w->show();
```

[image] [image]

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `QSpacerItem`.

```
QVBoxLayout* layout = new QVBoxLayout;
layout->addWidget(new QPushButton("first"));
layout->addWidget(new QPushButton("second"));
layout->addWidget(new QPushButton("third"));
layout->addWidget(new QPushButton("fourth"));
layout->addItem(new QSpacerItem(0, 0, QSizePolicy::Fixed, QSizePolicy::Expanding));
layout->addWidget(new QPushButton("fifth"));
```